# Does direction of current flow affect induced current?

Tags: current, pcb-design, inductance

I am working on a pcb design. On the board there are two separate areas where I have a constant 5VDC trace running close to and parallel to another trace which has a pulse-width modulated 5V signal going through it. In one of the cases I can see the pulse width modulated signal being induced onto the 5VDC line. With my oscilloscope I measure a peak-to-peak volatge of about 350mV on the signal that should be constant. In the other case I can not detect the pulse-width-modulated signal being induced at all. The only difference between the two areas of the board is that in one case the current in the traces is traveling in the same direction, in the other case the current is traveling in opposite directions. I remember from my Electromagnetics course that the direction of current flow changes the direction of the magnetic field. Is it possible that in one case the magnetic fields are being cancelled out but in the other case they are being added or something? Has anyone see this before?

Comment: Can you describe the location of the return traces (0v) for each of these signals? The electric field is between the send and return traces.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the device generating the PWM signal is powered from the trace that shows the interference? It could then be something a simple as a voltage drop caused by the varying load of the PWM driver. Also: What frequency does the PWM have? Are you sure it is not some unintended pick-up with the probe (i.e. PCB trace is clean, just the probe shows the signal)? Are you using a short ground clip wire connected directly to the board? Have you tried different grounded areas or traces for the ground clip?

Answer (score 1):

It may be inductance but things like this are hardly ever that simple. If the spikes you are seeing are at the turn on and turn off edges of the PWM signal my bet is that it DOES have a capacitance coupling component. Just because trace capacitance is small doesn't mean it won't couple. It is the relative capacitance trace to trace and trace to other low impedance (be it ground or a power rail).

Ceramic capacitors are usually good for taking care of noise issues like these. The trick is where to put them. Make sure to have some on IC rails and close to switching circuit where high dI/dt signals reside.

Also make sure that the scope probe ground you are using is small and very near the signal you are measuring. The signal you are seeing could be radiating into the scope probe and fooling you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and your power supply may have a different immpedence above the 5V than below since in one case spikes will go up and the other down (but the falling edge will make a spike the other way)

But I suspect it's more likely capacitive coupling - try thinking of the wires as a distributed resistance (and inductance) and the capacitive coupling as a bunch of caps - in one case with the sources at the same end and in the other with one at each end

(you may need to make the traces thicker to change the resistance)

but also try moving your scope ground around to see if what you are seeing on both traces is real

Comment: I don't think it's capacitive coupling. The capacity of two parallel traces is only in the order of 1 pF/cm.

Comment: Regulators don't have different impedances above and below 5V. The impedance of the 5V supply line varies with freq. You can try decoupling the 5V line to increase it's high freq impedance.

Comment: @Hendrik: linear regulators act as small resistance when they sense the output voltage is too low, and at other times act as a high resistance when they sense the output voltage is too high.

Answer (score 0):

The coupling mechanism should only change sign when the direction changes.

But the effect may be quite different.  If you have the direction of current flow going in different directions, presumably it is being driven by different devices with different driver designs and/or different power supply bypassing characteristics.

Also high and low drivers may have different impedance, so the effect on a signal that is high may be different than the effect on one that is low.

Also, you don't know that it's the trace coupling.  It could be some other means of coupling such as the power supply (especially if the interfering and interfered with signal are driven from the same chip or the same area of the board)